# fscanf command won't recognize spaces

Tags: c, text, printf, scanf, spaces

I am trying to write a program that edits a text file containing the expenses of a user on codeblock.

**stage one:** there is a file name "abc.txt". It states the current amount and the expenditures per date. Using a loop, I copy "abc.txt" to another file, "test.txt".

**stage two:** with another loop I request the user to add a new date and new amount that will either be subtracted or added to the total amount.

**stage three:** I close both files and copy the "test.txt" file (which contains all the updated info) to the original abc.txt" file using another loop.

The problem is in the last stage; when copying the text, whitespace is not preserved.

If you want to use my code you should have 2 text files name "abc.txt" and "test.txt". leave the "test" file blank and in the "abc" file write this:

```
[0]       Total amount:    79179      [1]
[1]
[1]
[1]
[0] Date:   1.1.19  [1]
[0] Sub:    10000   70000   [1]
[1]
[0] Date:   2.1.19  [1]
[0] Add:    10000   80000   [1]
[1]
[0] Date:   3.1.19  [1]
[0] Sub:    499 79501   [1]
[1]
[0] Date:   4.1.19  [1]
[0] Sub:    322 79179   [1]
[1]
```

And then run this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    FILE * filepointer;
    filepointer=fopen("abc.txt","r");

    char name[100];
    char name1[1000];
    int num;
    int old_amount;
    char date[20];
    int flag=0;
    int amount;
    char action[10];
    int tit;

    FILE *test;
    test=fopen("test.txt","w");

    fscanf(filepointer,"%s %s %s %d", &name, &name, &name, &amount );
    printf("The total amount:   %d\n",amount);

    while(!feof(filepointer))
    {
        fscanf(filepointer,"%s",name );

        if(strcmp(name,"[1]")==0)
        {
            printf("\n");
            fprintf(test,"[1]\n");
            fscanf(filepointer,"%s  ",name );
        }
            printf("%s  ",name);
            fprintf(test,name);
            fprintf(test,"   ");
    }

    printf("Enter date: ");
    scanf("%s",&date);

    printf("date: %s\n ",date);
    fprintf(test,"\n[0]   Date:   ");
    fprintf(test,date);
    fprintf(test,"     [1]\n");

    while(flag==0)
        {
            fflush(stdin);
            printf("What is th amount: ");
            scanf("%d",&num);


            printf("[0] %d\nstate action [S] [A]: ",num);
            scanf("%s",&action);


            if(strcmp(action,"a")==0 || strcmp(action,"A")==0)
            {
                fprintf(test,"\n[0]    Add:     %d      ",num);

                amount=amount+num;
                fprintf(test,"%d    [1]\n",amount);
                printf("OK");
            }

            if(strcmp(action,"s")==0 || strcmp(action,"S")==0)
            {
                fprintf(test,"\n[0]    Sub:     %d      ",num);

                amount=amount-num;
                fprintf(test,"%d    [1]\n",amount);
                printf("OK");
            }


            printf("\nDo you wish to add another value?[Y] [N]\n");
            scanf("%s",&action);

            if(strcmp(action,"n")==0 || strcmp(action,"N")==0)
            {
                flag=1;
            }
        }
    fclose(test);
    fclose(filepointer);

    FILE * text;
    text=fopen("test.txt","r");


    FILE *abc;
    abc=fopen("abc.txt","w");

    fprintf(abc,"\n[0]       Total amount:    %d      [1]\n",amount);


    while(!feof(text))
    {
        fscanf(text,"%s",&name1 );

        if(strcmp(name1,"[1]")==0)
        {
            //printf("       GOT IT   \n");
            fprintf(abc,"[1]\n");
            fscanf(text,"%s  ",&name1 );
        }
            printf("%s  ",name1);
            fprintf(abc,"%s ",name1);
            fprintf(abc,"   ");
    }


    return 0;
}
```

When I run it in a project file it works fine, but when I run in as an application it causes trouble... any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a [debugger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugger) to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: See: [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5431941/253056)

Comment: And the `"%s"` format separates on space.

Comment: And failing to **validate the return** of `fscanf` is a recipe for disaster.

Comment: Managing spaces with the `scanf()` family of functions is hard.  See also [A Beginner's Guide Awy From `scanf()`](http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html).  Be wary of [using `fflush(stdin)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979209/). You'd probably do better using `fgets()` (or POSIX `getline()`) to read lines and then write them. By definition, `%s` skips over white space (including newlines), and then saves characters up to but not including the next white space. If you want to preserve spaces, it is simplest not to use `scanf()` et al; else use scan sets `%[…]`.

Comment: When I run it in a project file it works fine, but when I run in as an application it causes trouble... any ideas?

Comment: Why not edit your question and add your updated code **to the end** of your original question showing the updates you have made based on the suggestions in the comments above. That way we can address the current problem you are having instead of problems that may have already been addressed based on the comments. Do not change your original question, **add** your updated code at the end. (otherwise the comments and suggestions will no longer make sense)

Comment: "causes trouble" is not a useful description.   A useful description would be "when I run this my monitor shuts off", or "every time I run this a baby cries in the next room, which is weird because I don't have kids"

Comment: As I said: "The problem is in the last stage; when copying the text, white space is not preserved." I apologize for my bad English, I hope I made myself clear.